# How to do a 'ls | grep Service_Accounts' in a python script

Tags: python-2.7

I have a directory of csv files that I need to joing together. I have the code to do it if I use all the CSV files in the directory. how do I grep out the csv files I want.

Current Code:

```
import os
import csv

path = '/opt/csv/'
os.chdir(path)
all_domains = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
         with open(filename, 'r') as csvDataFile:
                csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
                next(csvReader)
                for row in csvReader:
                        all_domains.append(row)

all_csv = '/opt/csv/CSV.csv'
out_all_csv = open(all_csv, 'w')
outwriter = csv.writer(out_all_csv, delimiter=',')
outwriter.writerow(('user', 'Password_Last_Set', 'Password_Age'))

for domain in all_domains:
        outwriter.writerow(domain)
```

I have tried a variant of 
   f = os.popen('ls | grep')
   now = f.read()
   print "Today is ", now
and using the os.system()

Answer (score 0):

I used the listdir path and used an if statement to filter out my results

Answer (score 0):

Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('Service_Accounts*.csv'):
   with open(filename) as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
        print('Do something')
```